# Can't access Laravel helper class from a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have my Helper file located at `app/Helpers/Helper.php`

```
class Helper {

    // Add body class
    public static function bodyClass() {
        $body_classes = array();
        $class = "";

        foreach ( \Request::segments() as $segment ) {
            if ( is_numeric( $segment ) || empty( $segment ) ) {
            continue;
            }

            $class .= ! empty( $class ) ? "-" . $segment : $segment;
            array_push( $body_classes, $class );
        }
        return ! empty( $body_classes ) ? implode( ' ', $body_classes ) : NULL;
    }
}
```

Then in my `composer.json`, I autoloaded this Helper file like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
    ]
},
```

Then in one of my master views, I have this:

`<body class="{{ Helper::bodyClass() }}">`

But I get an error saying:

`Class 'Helper' not found`

I also did dump autoload so that shouldn't be the issue.  Anyone have any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** You need add namespace for your `Helper` class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class Helper {
    ...
}
```

**2.** If you wanna use your class in view, then you need to add alias for your class.

`config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [
    ...

    'Helper' => 'App\Helpers\Helper'
]
```

Done!

P.s: You don't need to add your class into `composer.json` autoload. It's unneeded.

Comment: Oh that's awesome.  Much better than autoloading.  Thanks! :)